# Python function that generates random arrays of integers not working

Tags: python, random, numbers

I need to create a function  that generates random arrays of integers between a and b, inclusive, where a and b define the range and M and N define the size of the output array. I've done something but it seems that it's not properly working and **I don't know exactly how can I define the size of the output array, where exactly to put M and N**.....Here it's my code:

```
import random 

def Rand(start, end, num): 
    res = [] 

    for j in range(num): 
        res.append(random.randint(start, end)) 

    return res 

# Driver Code 
num = 10
start = 20
end = 40
print(Rand(start, end, num))
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me, what's your problem ? What are M and N, you ned only `num`

Comment: "it seems that it's not properly working ": What evidence do you have that it isn't working properly?

Comment: the problem is that I can't define the range of the output array(for example 5 lines and 4 columns)

Comment: _M and N define the size of the output array_ Why do 2 variables determine the size of a 1d list?...Edit: Is it a 2d list?

Comment: I don't understand why u downvote me, I was looking for a solution similar to what David gave to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need two nested loops (or a nested list comprehension)

For example:

```
import random

def random_array(start, end, a, b):

    return [[random.randint(start, end) for _ in range(a)] for _ in range(b)]

# Driver Code
a = 10
b = 5
start = 20
end = 40
print(random_array(start, end, a, b))
```

Which, in my case, output:

```
[[35, 27, 30, 27, 26, 37, 38, 27, 36, 34], [24, 24, 29, 35, 27, 38, 38, 37, 24, 24], [35, 20, 38, 25, 26, 20, 31, 29, 27, 33], [37, 36, 34, 20, 27, 30, 33, 26, 24, 26], [28, 35, 20, 31, 33, 36, 29, 25, 36, 36]]
```

If you don't want to use list comprehensions (although you probably should), it would be the equivalent of:

```
def random_array(start, end,  a, b):
    res = []
    for _ in range(b):
        inner = []
        for _ in range(a):
            inner.append(random.randint(start, end))
        res.append(inner)
    return res
```

Final note: According to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) you shouldn't start a function name with a capital letter.